# Is it possible to move ImageButtons with an onClick in a relative view?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

My intension is to have a button on screen that when clicked will move a bunch of imagebuttons from one "football formation" to another one.

Something along the lines of this.

[image: Formation 1]

To this [image: Formation 2]

With each position representing a different imageButton, however when i try something like

player2.setLeft(200);

It crashes the program.

If this View isn't possible for this what would be the best way to go about it, or am i best off using a different layout entirely?

Comment: When it crashes, what exception is thrown?  Also, what versions of Android are you targeting?

Comment: have you tried removing the view, updating the layout params then readding it?

Comment: From 11 (3.0 i believe) upwards.

I run the program and it just says "programName has crashed unexpectedly."

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry still quite new to this, where do i find the stack trace?